# Reference Classes from Application Package to Unit Testing Package

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans, project

I've been trying to import classes of the package to another package for unit testing. That's my idea for now. I have two packages one is the package of the main application and the other one is for package for testing the application. What's the best practice for doing unit testing? Is my approach correct? Also, I didn't figure out how to actually import classes in that case. If I go about adding libraries, if I share the testing package with someone, they shouldn't have to do it again. I mean it should be sufficient to place the package in the path where the actual application resides.

Spec- java project, netbeans ide

Comment: What do you mean _I didn't figure out how to actually import classes in that case_? Just use `import your.package.Class`. That class will have to be on the compilation class path.

Comment: I mean i tried to add import statement but it said package doesn't exist.....I don't know how to import classes from another project

Comment: You have to add the other project to your classpath/buildpath.

Comment: Then  is it sufficient to share the testing project provided that other person already have the application project? does the person need to add the path again in that case?

Comment: Your unit testing project uses classes from your application project. You will need to change the Netbeans unit testing project settings to include the application project on its build path. If you're distributing this project, you will need to package it to include the application project (maybe as a jar).